# how to include a function in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

for the report of an assignment I want to include functions like this one in my report, but there appears to be some error and I cannot find it. The function runs in the console but R markdown says:
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : :7:11: unexpected '}' 6: + x <- x/2 7: } ^ calls:  ...  -> parse_all -> parse_all.character -> parse

This is the function:
`{r echo=FALSE}
collatz <- function(x){
+     steps <- c();
+     stepCounter <- 0;
+     while(x>1){
+         if(x%%2==0){
+             x <- x/2
+         } else { 
+             x <- 3*x+1
          }
+         stepCounter <- stepCounter+1
+         steps[stepCounter] <- x}
+     print(paste(c("steps:", steps), collapse=" "))
+     print(paste("number of iterations:",stepCounter))}`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `+` in your document? Removing them leads to a working document.

````
---
title: "function"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r echo=F}
collatz <- function(x) {
    steps <- c()

    stepCounter <- 0

    while (x > 1) {
        if (x %% 2 == 0) {
            x <- x / 2
        } else {
            x <- 3 * x + 1
        }
        stepCounter <- stepCounter + 1
        steps[stepCounter] <- x
    }
    print(paste(c("steps:", steps), collapse = " "))
    print(paste("number of iterations:", stepCounter))
}
collatz(3)
```
````

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works now. Why does the console include the + at the beginning of each line but r markdown cannot run it?

Comment: The console is intended for interactive use.  It uses the `+` to prompt you to type more, because it can tell that the code is incomplete.  When it comes to the end of your function definition, the prompt switches back to `>`.